# Where is "comparision" as spelling of "comparison" coming from?

Tags: orthography

From time to time I encounter *comparision* as common "alternative" spelling for *comparison* (mostly while browsing questions on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=comparision)). I don't recall encountering any other (mis)spelling this often.

- [On this site](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=comparision) there are 14 results as of before posting this question (all of them are not *about* the spelling).
- [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?search=comparision) does not have an entry and suggests "Did you mean: *comparison*", but nevertheless refers to 4 entries containing quotations with that spelling.
- [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/spellcheck/english/?q=comparision) also does not have an entry for it.

I suspected that this spelling is used by non-native speakers transferring their own spelling, but e.g. in French, which seemed most likely to me, it is [*comparaison*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/comparaison).

Is there a particular reason for this spelling? Is it historical? Is it regional?

Or is it simply wrong, and people are copying it without knowing better?

Comment: It's just a typo, a repeated letter I where it shouldn't be, probably by analogy with vision, concision, and lots of other words. People make mistakes, and mistakes often follow patterns. There's no great mystery to it.

Comment: @StuartF Whether this is so was my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Comparision* is not a recognised spelling, and it has never been:

OED

> **Forms**:  Middle English comparisoun, comparysoun(e, Middle English–1500s comparyson, comparisone, (Middle English comparrison, comparsoun, comparicon), 1500s compareson(e, comparason, Middle English– comparison.

The word "comparison" has remained constant in its spelling from the 15th century:

1481   W. Caxton tr. Myrrour of Worlde iii. xxi. 181   *So moche a debonayer lorde..that ther is no comparison to hym.*

Its OED etymology,

> **Etymology:** < Old French comparaison, compareson = Provençal comparasó , Spanish comparacion , Italian comparazione < Latin comparātiōn-em , noun of action < comparāre,

does not support the "comparision" version.